# Is there a Latin word for "vessel", as in a human receiver or holder or something

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

I'm looking for a Latin word for "vessel", which in English can mean a person who receives or holds something immaterial. Options I've found so far are *receptor*,*acceptor*, *gerulus*, and *bajulus* (which had alternate spellings of *baijulus* and *bajolus*).

I'm not sure if any of those conveys quite the same flavor that vessel does for a person in English, though. To me what is most important is that the thing being carried or held is not physical.

Comment: Perhaps there's a better answer, but honestly, I'd just use one of the many Latin words for a container for physical objects (capsa, capsella, locellus, loculus, loculamentum, receptaculum, thesaurus, etc.), with the immaterial thing that is held added in the genitive. At most, I'd add a form of quidam in agreement with the container word, to signal a figurative usage, as I see writers such as Pliny the Younger do – e.g., quidam thesaurus virtutis.

Comment: That makes sense. Something like _capsellae memoriae imperfectae_, or _quaedam capsellae memoriae imperfectae_? For context this is a descriptive statement being directed at someone else (in this case the someone is plural).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest [**vas, -is**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvas2), which has the somewhat unusual plural **vasa, -orum**.

The first thing I thought of when I heard the word "vessel" was II Corinthians 4:7. Here, St. Paul speaks of how an immaterial gift ("the light of the knowledge of God's glory") is received in our fragile bodies:

> But we have this treasure in **earthen vessels**, that the excellency may be of the power of God, and not of us.

Here's the original Greek:

> ἔχομεν δὲ τὸν θησαυρὸν τοῦτον **ἐν ὀστρακίνοις σκεύεσιν**, ἵνα ἡ ὑπερβολὴ τῆς δυνάμεως ᾖ τοῦ θεοῦ καὶ μὴ ἐξ ἡμῶν. . . .

And here's Jerome's Vulgate translation:

> Habemus autem thesaurum istum **in vasis fictilibus**: ut sublimitas sit virtutis Dei, et non ex nobis.

(N.B. It appears that Jerome construes "δυνάμεως" with "θεοῦ," not "ὑπερβολὴ." I'm not sure if this is due to a difference in source text. I used the Douay-Rheims English translation above, which corresponds to Jerome's Latin text.)

Comment: I don't know any ancient greek, but this is a great example of the usage of the word in a similar context. Thanks!