# Is my translation of "You are imperfect vessels of memories and you corrupt their perfection" into Latin correct?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

In a previous question I asked for a [word that could be used to mean *vessel*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14870/is-there-a-latin-word-for-vessel-as-in-a-human-receiver-or-holder-or-somethin), in the sense that it is a person holding something immaterial.

I'm now translating the rest of the sentence that includes *vessel*:

> You are imperfect vessels of memories and you corrupt their perfection.

I currently have the following:

> Vos (quaedam) vasa memoriarum imperfectarum estis et perfectiones suum foedatis.

I have *quaedam* in parenthesis because I feel it's optional, but might be needed to better convey what I want.

Does this make sense given the English version? For greater context, the person speaking this is a deity in a mythology I've created, and they are explaining why memories are inherently faulty even though they made memories to be perfect recollections of the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so much a complete answer, but several points to consider.

- I think the word *perfectus* usually has the connotation of something completed/finished/done, and somewhat less in the sense of whole/pure/without-blemish; For the latter sense the adjective *integer* is perhaps closer. I didn't find a good one-word-match for imperfect (corruptus sounds too strong for me)
- Note that in the English version *imperfect* modifies *vessels*, but it seems in the Latin it modifies memories (i.e. "you are vessels of imperfect memories").
- I wonder about the *suum* there. *suus* as an adjective should match its noun. In our case it is *perfectiones* which is acc. pl. f. so it should appear as *suas*.
- Also note that *suus* "is used only as a reflexive, referring to the subject. For a possessive pronoun of the 3rd person not referring to the subject, the genitive of a demonstrative must be used"([A&G](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/possessive-pronouns-paradigm)(thanks to Sebastian Koppehel for pointing that out)). So it seems it would be correct to use *earum* instead of *suas*, as the subject here is *vos* and not the *memoriea*.
- Other than that it seems quite good for me.

Comment: "I suspect it should not be suas but earum" -- that is also my understanding, at least so it should be according to good classical grammar. See [Allen & Greenough](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/possessive-pronouns-paradigm).

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks for your help, guys! I had a feeling that suum wasn't what I wanted when I wanted to refer to the object.

Comment: Quick followup question: does *Vos vasa non integra memoriarum* make sense using _integer_?

Comment: @Adam, Yes I think it makes sense. you are imperfect vessels of memories.